# Second order nonlinear delay differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I have to solve the following delay differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}(t)+A\sin(\omega x(t-\tau))=0$$
Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this equation?
Thanks

Comment: Hello Riccardo, it will be nice if you provide some insight on actual problem itself. This is SHM question, I suppose.

Comment: Yes. It's a problem coming from Tracking filtering theory. It's something like a pendulum in which the stress transmitted to the mass depends on the previous instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is the following. Consider the Green function for the problem
$$
   \ddot G(t) = \delta(t)
$$
that in your case takes the simple form $G(t-t')=(t-t')\theta(t-t')$. Then,
$$
   x(t)=-\int_0^t(t-t')\theta(t-t')A\sin(\omega x(t'-\tau))dt'+x_0+v_0t.
$$
You can solve this equation iteratively, starting with $x(t)=x(0)+\dot x(0)t$, and will recognize that, already at the second order, Bessel functions come out.

If you have the conditions $x_1=x(t_1)$ and $x_2=x(t_2)$ the Green function takes the form
$$
   G(t,t')=-\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\left[(t'-t_2)(t-t_1)\theta(t'-t)+(t'-t_1)(t-t_2)\theta(t-t')\right]
$$
and you have to cope with a more involved integral but the conclusions do not change.